# Example on how to setup continous delivery pipeline with ARM for a serverless application in azure

Tags: azure, configuration, azure-devops, continuous-deployment, serverless

Coming from Firebase where setting up a whole serverless application with Authentication, File Storage, Database,Cloud Functions and Hosting is quite straight forward, we are currently investigating how to achieve something similar with Azure. After reading some docs and studying samples, I find solutions for setting up those components independently but nothing really concrete how to manage them in combination.

The main questions I have are:

- **Continous Deployment with Staging**: How can I do a proper staging in Azure when I have configured a serverless application with functions, database, authentication etc.? In firebase there is a json file defining my backend and I can deploy it to the firebase project i want (e.g. myapp-dev, myapp-test, myapp-prod). Is there something similiar in Azure? For webapps I found the "slots" but for DB, Storage, API Gateway etc. - how can I do this in Azure? I guess one should use the Azure Pipelines, but is there any proper documentation or example on how to handle all the components of a serverless application with this?
- **Config-As-Code**: Most documentation/tutorials in Azure start with either doing the complete configuration in the Azure Portal UI, or in Visual Studio (Code). As a Team we want all the configuration in a git repo and maintain it from there right from the start. I guess the Azure Resource Manager (ARM) is for this? If so - what is the recommended approach to ramp up serverless projects with ARM?

*Side Note*: We use Node.js for functions in Backend. So no .NET or Java.

Comment: This is a very big question but you can do all this with a combination of Azure DevOps pipelines, ARM templates (or Azure cli but I prefer ARM as they’re idempotent) and staging slots. We use separate resources for staging for things like DBs and storage and you can create whole environments from ARM templates and then kill them off if you want to save costs. We’re doing all of this for more traditional architectures and starting to do the same for serverless as well. Authentication using Azure AD (B2C) is one pain point as you can’t create this with an ARM template.

Comment: @Matt thx. do you know any examples for ARM with common serverless scenarious (storage, db, api, functions) and pipeline?

Comment: I use the quick starts from the answer below and also the [main ARM doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/). Using the portal to try and figure out your deployments via Automation Options as described below is also useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you'll need to build this out yourself using ARM Templates. You can write nested templates, modules and extensions, dependencies, configurations etc.

You can sometimes get started by combining various solutions and deployments from the Quick Start Library:

- https://azure.microsoft.com/en-au/resources/templates/
- https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates

For more complex deployments I've pulled apart the Sitecore ARM templates purely for the deployment structure.

- https://github.com/Sitecore/Sitecore-Azure-Quickstart-Templates

You can also manually create resources in Azure Portal and click on "Automation Options" just before you Deploy to get the JSON required.

Out of the box though, Azure is severely lacking in solution based deployments.